# VK API wall.post получить <media_id>

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Всем привет. Пишу скрипт для добавления постов в группу:

```
    $dataSend = array(
        'owner_id'  => "-123456",
        'message'   => "Hello wall.post!",
        'attachments'=> "photo-123456_xxxxxxxxx"  // where xxxxxxxxx =  media_id
    ) ;
    $vkAPI->api("wall.post",$dataSend);
```

Работает, осталось прикрепить фото. Подскажите пож как получить `media_id` ?

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/wall.post

Comment: @ n.osennij hello. по этим docs и собирал $dataSend, нужно получить <media_id>

Comment: Там же указано:<media_id> — идентификатор медиа-приложения. 

Например:
photo100172_166443618,photo-1_265827614. Значит фото нужно загрузить сначала.

Comment: На пример, можно получить список фотографий методом `photos.getAll` и использовать `id` в качестве `<media_id>`.

Comment: Это понятно, а после получить `media_id`, которое необходимо подставить в attachments. Только как это сделать? Пытаюсь разобраться. Если у кого-нибудь есть опыт поделитесь пож

Comment: @webDev_ фото будут поститься с сайта, где в метод будет приходить аргумент $photo

Comment: @ultimatum после успешной загрузки файла возвращается JSON массив содержащий `ID`

Comment: @webDev_ как раз читаю об этом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот держите рабочий код:

```
    $accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $vkAPI = new \BW\Vkontakte(['access_token' => $accessToken]);
    $publicID = -$group_id; // group_id

    $getURL = array(
        'group_id'  => $group_id,
    );

    if($vkAPI->api("photos.getWallUploadServer",$getURL)){   // получаем upload_url
        $result = $vkAPI->api("photos.getWallUploadServer",$getURL);
    } else {
        echo "ERROR URI<BR>";
    }

    $curl = curl_init();  //загружаем фото и получаем photo_id и owner_id
    $file = DIR_IMAGE.'0qDLZ0kw0I.jpg';   // путь к загружаемому файлу
    $file = curl_file_create($file, mime_content_type($file),pathinfo($file)['basename']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $result['response']['upload_url']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $charset = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $charset );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['file' => $file]);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $response_image = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    curl_close($curl);

    $request_params = array(
        'group_id'=>"$group_id",
        'photo' => $response_image->photo,
        'server' => $response_image->server,
        'hash' => $response_image->hash,
    );

    $getPhoto = $vkAPI->api("photos.saveWallPhoto",$request_params);
    $photo_id = $getPhoto['response'][0]['pid'];
    $owner_id = $getPhoto['response'][0]['owner_id'];

    $dataSend = array(   // подготавливаем наш Post
        'owner_id'  => $publicID,
        'message'   => "I'm new Post!",
        'attachments'=> "photo".$owner_id."_".$photo_id.", https://google.com/"  // where photo_id = media_id
    ) ;

    if($vkAPI->api("wall.post",$dataSend)){
        $vkAPI->api("wall.post",$dataSend);
        echo "Post добавлен!<BR>";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR! Ищем ошибку<BR>";
    }
```

Инфа по докам описана, так что повторно добавлять не буду. Всем добра!

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы выяснить этот *media_id*, нужно вначале либо самостоятельно загрузить фотографию на сайт, прежде чем публиковать запись, либо взять уже загруженную ранее.

Для загрузки фотографии вам придётся выполнить несколько шагов:

1. Вызвать метод [photos.getWallUploadServer](https://vk.com/dev/photos.getWallUploadServer), передав ему параметр **group_id** с идентификатором группы, положительное число.
2. В ответ сервер пришлёт JSON объект, с полем **upload_url**, содержащем URL для загрузки файла. По этому адресу надо выполнить POST запрос с полем **photo**, которое будет содержать фотографию.
3. После надо будет передать данные, полученные на предыдущем шаге, методу [photos.saveWallPhoto](https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveWallPhoto). (Если не ничего не путаю, достаточно передать только параметр **photo**).
4. И только теперь есть смысл вызывать [wall.post](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post), как у вас в примере.

Подробнее процедура описана в документации на странице «[Загрузка файлов](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=2.%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83)».

Разумеется, если фото уже присутсвует на сайте к моменту публикации, то всё проще. Можно подглядеть этот *meida_id* в ссылке на фотографию.