# Как скриптом прикрепить фотографию к сообщению?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Мне нужно PHP скриптом прикрепить фотографию в ответ пользователю.
Я думал, что есть такая возможность в методе [messages.send](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send), там есть параметр **attachment**, но он позволяет прикрепить фотографию, которая уже существует на серверах ВК. Моя цель от определенного сообщения ответить нужной картинкой, которая находится у меня на сервере, соответственно грузить картинку будет скрипт, а не я. Я нашел метод [photos.getUploadServer](https://vk.com/dev/photos.getUploadServer), но тут беда в том, что тут должна быть форма для загрузки фотографий, которую придется отправить запросом Post. Как ее скрипт то заполнит и отправит? Не знаю как поступить в данной ситуации.

P.S. В ВК еще есть фишка, которая может прикрепить фотографию по ссылке. Я так обычно делаю, кидаю ссылку на фотографию в диалог, и фотография через секунду прикрепляется. Тут я хотел также сделать, хотя понимал что скорее всего не выйдет. Даже делал sleep(3), чтоб фотография прогрузилась на всякий случай, но кидается просто ссылка на картинку. Как поступить?

Comment: Гляньте, [как загружать фотографии к записям на стене](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/625076/183314). С сообщениями всё точно также, разве что названия методов понятным образом различаются. Подробнее [в документации](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=4.%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Comment: А если попробовать отправить сначала картинку себе в личные сообщение, а потом от туда переслать пользователю методом messages.send с параметром forward_messages.